# What's the point of adding event to interface?

Tags: contract-development, evm

Like in a sample code below.
Thanks.

```
interface ISomething {
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not?

Interface defines the required functionality. For example in the case of ERC-20, the standard also defines that those two events have to be defined. So the ERC20 interface lists the required functions and the required events.

So just by implementing the interface you can be sure to include the required functionality. Of course an interface can't dictate *how* you implement the functionality, but at least it's there.